# how to visible icon in all the items of recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to visible icons on all the items list of the recyclerview, what I want is that by pressing any on of the items, icons will be visible to all the list of the items.

help me to find out the solution.

here is my code

onBindViewholder

```
 imageList.get(position).setDeleteImage(holder.items_image);
    holder.items_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.wpImages.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        int i;
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            for (i = 0; i<=imageList.size();i++){
                if (imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add *notifyDataSetChanged()* after you update UI like this:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
   for (i = 0; i<=imageList.size();i++){
      if (imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
           imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }else {
           imageList.get(i).getDeleteImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged()
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I got this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13

Comment: ofcourse. in your for loop, firsr index = 0, so your last index must is imageList.size()-1. You can chage for loop like this : for (i = 0; i<=imageList.size() - 1;i++).              Or: for (i = 0; i<imageList.size();i++)

Comment: 19 thank you sooooooo much for helping me out of this problem....I am new learner in android developing.... one thing I want to know can I ask you question if I have any problem related to android

Comment: yes, I'm always ready. But you should create a question so others can help you